# RestClient not fetching entire webpage

Tags: ruby, web-scraping, nokogiri, screen-scraping, rest-client

I am trying to scrape http://rbi.org.in/home.aspx to fetch the exchange rates.

This is my code:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'nokogiri'
require 'restclient'
require 'json'

page = Nokogiri::HTML(RestClient.get("http://www.rbi.org.in/home.aspx"))
puts page.inspect
```

I do not get any of the `<table>` or `<span>` tags. All I get is:

```
<html>
<HEAD>
    <title>Reserve Bank of India - India's Central Bank</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
</HEAD>

<body>
<form name="ctl00" method="post" action="default.aspx" id="ctl00">
<div>
<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTTARGET" id="__EVENTTARGET" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTARGUMENT" id="__EVENTARGUMENT" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="/wEPDwUKLTY4NTY4ODMwOGRksjUIop3c9mHB1LiOzxhiEe+9uY0=" />
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var theForm = document.forms['ctl00'];
if (!theForm) {
    theForm = document.ctl00;
}
function __doPostBack(eventTarget, eventArgument) {
    if (!theForm.onsubmit || (theForm.onsubmit() != false)) {
        theForm.__EVENTTARGET.value = eventTarget;
        theForm.__EVENTARGUMENT.value = eventArgument;
        theForm.submit();
    }
}
//]]>
</script>


<div>

    <input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR" id="__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR" value="CA0B0334" />
    <input type="hidden" name="__EVENTVALIDATION" id="__EVENTVALIDATION" value="/wEWAwKzlrSzDgLtyMXRBgK++un9Ay2/rximKfZSRpQMBtYFf8ro5dRB" />
</div>
    <a id="lbtnSubmit" href="javascript:__doPostBack('lbtnSubmit','')"></a>
    <input name="txtResolution" type="hidden" id="txtResolution" />
</form>
<script language='javascript'>
document.getElementById("txtResolution").value="1024";
function goToHome()
{
    if ( (screen.width >= 1024) && (screen.height >= 768) )
    {
        document.getElementById("txtResolution").value="1024";
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById("txtResolution").value="800";
    }
    __doPostBack('lbtnSubmit','');
}
goToHome();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

How do I get the entire page source and parse the exchange rates? I have looked up all Nokogiri tutorials but they were of no help. Also I don't think this page is gzipped.

Comment: Nokogiri doesn't fetch pages. In your code, RestClient does it, and passes to Nokogiri what it received. So, your question is, why don't you get the entire page when you request it.

Answer (score 0):

Why just not to use OpenURI instead of RestClient for that?

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

r = Nokogiri::HTML(open("http://www.rbi.org.in/home.aspx"))

p r.inspect
```

Comment: Same result Andrey :(

Comment: ah, there is another problem. page is rendered on client side with javascript. You need to use something like PhantomJS to scrape page and then parse it with nokogiri.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the site uses JavaScript to redirect users to a page that creates an session for the user.

The reason you are not redirected is because RestClient does not evaluate JavaScript.

Comment: Pafjo, you are right. I just figured it out. But what is the way out? I really to parse the page.

Answer (score 0):

You can scrape page with Capybara with JavaScript.

These are the gem dependencies:

```
gem 'capybara'
gem 'selenium-webdriver'
```

and a preinstalled Firefox binary.

```
require 'capybara'

session = Capybara::Session.new(:selenium)
session.visit "http://rbi.org.in/home.aspx"

puts session.body
```